# Check for matching key in object regardless of capitalization

Tags: javascript, loops, object, search, capitalization

Given a key: `'mykey'`

And given an object: `Object {Mykey: "some value", ...}`

And using the following `if (key in myObject)` syntax to check for a match...

How can I check matching strings regardless of capital letters?

For example: key `mykey` should be matched to `Mykey` in the object even though the `M` is capitalized.

---

I am aware of a function to do this: [How to uppercase Javascript object keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408638/how-to-uppercase-javascript-object-keys)

I was looking to see if there was another way.

Comment: You can't, are you asking how to create a function that does that ?

Comment: Your retrieval function would be accepting potential collisions in the map based on an arbitrary logic shim. I don't think this is a built-in feature, you're best bet might be to insert this as a custom function (like the example @adeneo gave) in the prototype chain and inherit from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a function that does this, there's no native case-insensitive way to check if a key is in an object

```
function isKey(key, obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj).map(function(x) {
        return x.toLowerCase();
    });

    return keys.indexOf( key.toLowerCase() ) !== -1;
}
```

used like

```
var obj    = {Mykey: "some value"}
var exists = isKey('mykey', obj); // true
```

Comment: You are my hero bro

Answer (score 0):

follow this example

```
var myKey = 'oNE';
var text = { 'one' : 1, 'two' : 2, 'three' : 3};
for (var key in text){
if(key.toLowerCase()==myKey.toLowerCase()){
//matched keys
    console.log(key)
}else{
//unmatched keys
    console.log(key)
}

}
```

[JavaScript: case-insensitive search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177719/javascript-case-insensitive-search)