# Capitalize words in a string - taking into account parenthesis etc

Tags: javascript

I've been reviewing the answers on [How to capitalize the first letter of each word in a string using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589197/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-using-javascript) but yet can't get any to work.

I'm trying to capitalize the first letter of each word in a string. But with an example such as `I'm an example (for stack overflow).` the word `for` is not capitalized.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This in fact depends on what you will consider the start of the sentence. Does text after ( or [ or " or ' or < or { mean the start of a sentence? Will this `<for stack overflow>` also need to change to `<For Stack Overflow>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex - `^([a-z])|[ (]+([a-z])` which says "every letter after a space or `(`. (If there are more cases, add them to the pattern)

And the code is

```js
const result = `i'm an example (for stack overflow).`
  .replace(/^([a-z])|[ (]+([a-z])/g, l => l.toUpperCase())
  
console.log(result);
```

You can play with the regex here: https://regex101.com/r/gkZvyt/1

Comment: Thank you, how can I combine this so it makes the entire sentence capitalized for each word?

Comment: What do you mean? What should be the result?

Comment: Thanks @StephenP, You're right. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I'm afraid this still doesnt work with the first character of a string being lowercase, thanks anyway.

Comment: I built the regex based on your example. If I understand you correctly you want to uppercase also that expression - `i'm an example (for stack overflow).`. I've updated the answer to handle that case too..

Comment: Thanks for all your help.

Comment: My pleasure  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It is actually simple using regex.

Replace the ^ symbol, which means only capitalize the beginning of the sentence.

For more information and play with regex, click [Here](https://regexr.com/).

```js
 const capitalize = str =>
  str.replace(/(?:\s|["([{])+\S/g, match => match.toUpperCase());
console.log(capitalize("I'm an example (for stack overflow)."));
```

Comment: Thank you, how can I combine this so it makes the entire sentence capitalized for each word?

Comment: @panthro changed the answer, is this what you meant?

Comment: I'm afraid this still doesnt work with the first character of a string being lowercase, thanks anyway.