# Uppercase first letter in moment js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

Is there a way to have just the first letter in uppercase using momment js?

```
Current output:

moment([20016, 0, 29]).fromNow(); // 4 years ago


Expected output:

moment([2016, 0, 29]).fromNow(); // 4 Years Ago
```

Comment: Not an answer, since momentjs might have a built-in way to do it -- but would https://www.npmjs.com/package/title-case suit your needs?

Comment: According to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/5031, one of the Moment js maintainer said "I don't think capitalization preferences should be a concern in Moment.js ." So use the link @TrentBing just offered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  .capitalize {
   text-transform: capitalize;
  }
```

Applying the following class will give you the desired effect.

Edit:

If CSS isn't your thing, there is a few different examples of how to do it using JS [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589197/how-can-i-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-using-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.prototype.replace()` with `regex` to achieve this:

```js
console.log(moment([2016, 0, 29]).fromNow().replace(/\b[a-z]/, match => match.toUpperCase()));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

`String.prototype.replace()` also gets a function as a second argument:

> A function to be invoked to create the new substring to be used to replace the matches to the given regexp or substr.

[String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way.

```js
console.log(moment([2016, 0, 29]).fromNow().split(' ').map(word => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1)).join(' '));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```