# How can I capitalize a string?

Tags: javascript

I have this string using JavaScript:

```
let str = "my city is beautiful."
```

I would like to get:

```
"My City Is Beautiful"
```

I tried this:

```
str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1)
```

But I got:

```
My city is beautiful
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589197/how-can-i-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-using-javascript

Comment: Also here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/js-capitalizing-strings

Answer (score 2):

you can use `split`, `map` and `join`:

```js
"my city is beautiful"
  .split(" ")
  .map(s => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1))
  .join(" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `map` and `join`.

```js
let str = "my city is beautiful."

var newStr = str.split(" ").map( str =>  str.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+ str.substring(1)).join(' ')

console.log(newStr)
```

Note the logic here is:

- Split each word
- Iterate using `map` and, for each word: Set uppercase to first value and append the rest of the word using `substring(1)`.
- And join all values to get the phrase again.

Answer (score 1):

```
const string = "my city is beautiful.";
const words = string.split(" ");

for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    words[i] = words[i][0].toUpperCase() + words[i].substr(1);
}

let newString = words.join(" ");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. split up the string into words
2. capitalize the first letter of each word
3. join the words back into a single string

```js
let str = "my city is beautiful."
const result =

  // split up the string into words
  str.split(' ')
  
  // capitalize the first letter of each word
  .map(word => {
    const [firstChar, ...rest] = word;
    return [firstChar.toUpperCase(), ...rest].join('');
  })
  
  // join the words back into a single string
  .join(' ');
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is cycle through every word in your string and modify it individually.
You can do that using **split()**.

```
let str = "my city is beautiful."
let newStr = "" // Create temporary string

let words = str.split(" ") // Split the string into words and store them in array
for (word of words) { // Cycle through the array
    let newWord = word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1) // Modify every word in the array
    newStr += (newWord + " ") // Append the word to the new String and add a space to the 
end
}

console.log(newStr.trim()) // Removes the spaces at the beginning and the end
// Output:
// "My City Is Beautiful."
```

Or a shorter approach:

```
let str = "my city is beautiful."
let newStr = ""

for (word of str.split(" "))
  newStr += (word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1) + " ")

console.log(newStr.trim())
// Output:
// "My City Is Beautiful."
```

Answer (score 0):

Learn how to here:

[Basic Algorithm Scripting: Title Case a SentencePassed](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-algorithm-scripting/title-case-a-sentence)

[freeCodeCamp Challenge Guide: Title Case a Sentence](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/freecodecamp-challenge-guide-title-case-a-sentence/16088)

```js
let str = "my city is beautiful."

let newstr = str.toLowerCase().replace(/(^|\s)\S/g, L => L.toUpperCase());
console.log(newstr)
```