# JavaScript subarray Iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, mapping, sub-array

I want to capitalize the first letter of every word in a string.

I want to know why this is not working:

```
function titleCase(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  for(let i = 0; i<ar.lrngth;i++){
    ar[i][0] = ar[i][0].toUpperCase();
  }
  return ar;
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

Nor this:

```
function titleCase(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  let _ar = [];
  _ar =str.map(item => item.map( cap => cap.toUpperCase()));
  return _ar;
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

I would like to know if there are any one liners that can do this too : same operation on elements of subarrays

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I capitalize the first letter of each word in a string using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589197/how-can-i-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-using-javascript)

Comment: @MajedBadawi yes it does solve the problem, i want to know wh my code isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are `immutable` in JavaScript and it is not an array of characters.

```js
const str = "Test";

str[0] = "K";

console.log(str);
```

It won't change the `string`  as you can see in the above example.

> When we use bracket notation for character access, we cannot delete or assign a new value. If we do, it silently fails. [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#character_access)

So we need to assign a new `string`  with the `uppercase`  first character and rest as it is.

What you can also do is. `Split`  array into a character array and `uppercase` the first character and `join`  them. But here still we are creating a new array with split and after joining the array we get the new string.

```js
let str = "test string";

str = str.split("");
str[0] = str[0].toUpperCase();
str = str.join("");
console.log(str);
```

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  console.log(str);
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    str[i] = str[i][0].toUpperCase() + str[i].slice(1);
  }
  return str.join(" ");
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

Comment: thanks, could you please explain to me why this didn't work ```str[i][0] = str[i][0].toUpperCase();```

Comment: @Majd reason added

Answer (score 1):

Here is good one line answer with es6 style - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43376967/15348051

Additionally, I Think the reason why it is not working is your code try to change Primitive value `str[i][0]` not reference type variable `str`'s  array element.

```js
for(let i = 0; i<ar.lrngth;i++){
    str[i][0] = str[i][0].toUpperCase(); // this one
}
```

you try like this

```
let aa = "i'm"
aa[0] = "I" // #2
console.log(aa) // "i'm"
```

this is not working, because variable `aa` is assigned primitive type string `"i'm"`. So when you assign it like `#2` in the code, you tried to change primative type not the variable `aa`

this is reference type example.

```
const aa = ["i","'","m"]
aa[0] = "I"
console.log(aa) // ["I","'","m"]
```

It works. Because it tried to change the array's element. array and object can change their elements by index or key.

I hope I explain it right :)

Answer (score 0):

See if that works:

```
  function capitalize(text) {
    let str = text.toLowerCase();
    str = str.replace(/(^\w{1})|(\s{1}\w{1})/g, match => match.toUpperCase());

  ;    return str;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to capitalize all words in a sentence.

```js
  const titleCase = (str) => {
      let initValue = str[0].toUpperCase();
      for (let i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i - 1] === " ") {
          initValue += str[i].toUpperCase();
        } else {
          initValue += str[i];
        }
      }
      return initValue;
    };

    const result = titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
     console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, ar is not defined. Also `for(let i = 0; i<ar.lrngth;i++){` lrngth should be length. If you define ar as `var ar = []` still it not work at  `ar[i][0] = ar[i][0].toUpperCase();` since there was no element in ar[i][0] to uppercase. To work your code, it can be modified as follows,

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  var ar = str;
  
  for(let i = 0; i< ar.length; i++){
    var element = ar[i].split('');
    element[0] = element[0].toUpperCase();
    ar[i] = element.join("");    
  }
  return ar.join(" ");
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

This way also works.

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  console.log(str);
  
  str = str.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  
  for(let i = 0; i<str.length; i++){
    str[i] = str[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str[i].slice(1);
  }
  
  return str.join(" ");
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```