# Auto Capitalization of Input value in React

Tags: css, reactjs, forms, frontend, antd

so I have an input field that accepts any input the user types and I've already made it look like it has auto capitalization of first letter using CSS styles: `textTransform: capitalize` but when I assign a useState variable to the input field, the value isn't properly capitalize as shown on the input field. I want the useState variable's value to have proper capitalization as shown in the input field.

Here's my simple code:

```
import {useState} from "react"
import "./styles.css";
import {Input} from "antd";

export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("")
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Input placeHolder="Type Something" style={{textTransform:"capitalize"}} onChange={(e)=>{setText(e.target.value)}}/>
      <br/>
      value = {text}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also here's a [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-kilby-5ufnp6?file=/src/App.js:0-364) for better visualization

Comment: You can do something like `e.target.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase();`

Comment: @MajorProductions Hello, upon trying the value would only record or store the first letter of the string typed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the value of the input when passing it to the state:

```js
onChange={(e) => {
  setText(e.target.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + e.target.value.slice(1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks but how would I be able to make it to capitalize only the first letter of the string? :)

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks for the link it helped me out a lot but I'm almost there, I want my values to look like this "Text Value" but with the current code I am getting "Text value"

Comment: You can try that then:
`setText(e.target.replace(/(^\w|\s\w)/g, m => m.toUpperCase()));`.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60610887/5103610

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code below:

```js
import React,{useEffect, useState} from "react"
const Home=()=>{
  const [text, setText] = useState("")
  const changeInput = (e)=>{
    let str = e.target.value;
  let con =   str.split(' ')
    .map(function (word, index) {
      // First character upper case else lower case
      return word.charAt(0)
        .toUpperCase() + word.slice(1)
        .toLowerCase();
    })
    .join(' ');
    setText(con);
  }
 
  return (
    <div>
      <input placeHolder="Type Something" style={{textTransform:"capitalize"}} onChange={(e)=>changeInput(e)}/>
      <br/>
      value = {text}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const handlecapClick = () => {    
    let newtext = text.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + text.slice(1);
    setText(newtext);
  };
```