# JavaScript String Reverse and Capitalized

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a simple solution to build Javascript a function through which I can reverse a word or a string.

I have gone through `.split('').reverse().join('')` solution from the community to reverse it correctly but now I am stuck on Capitalizing on Each First Character.

```
let ar = "looking for opportunities"
const a =(ar)=> {return ar.split('').reverse().join('')}
```

and then I am stuck. I need a solution that can serve both sentence and word.

Required Output : seitinutroppO roF gnikooL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex.

```
let ar = "looking for opportunities"
ar = ar.replaceAll(/\w\S*/g,
    function(txt) {
      return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    }
)
const a =(ar)=> {return ar.split('').reverse().join('')}
```

This matches all characters after a space, then replaces it with an uppercase version.

Comment: Why StackOverflow Bot suggested it as the wrong question? It completely missed the reverse word. It refers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589197/how-can-i-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-using-javascript

Comment: @ArkaBhattacharjee Your code to reverse the string works. Simply capitalize each letter first, then reverse.

Comment: is there any other way to avoid regex and limited it inside string only?

Comment: @ArkaBhattacharjee Try `ar.split(' ').map(e => [...(e[0].toUpperCase() + e.substr(1))].reverse().join('')).reverse().join(' ')`, which uses an array-only approach